# Retreiving a user cookie

Tags: drupal

I am trying to retreive an user cookie with an http-request with drupal. I am using:

- Postman
- Acquia Dev Desktop 2

When I POST: `drupal-8-7-1.dd:8083/user/login?_format=json` with a body of `{"name": "drupal", "pass": "drupal"}`, which contains account credentials.

I am expecting to retreive a 200 OK, a request cookie and a response object.

What happens however is that I get a 403 FORBIDDEN and a response object containing: `{"message":"This route can only be accessed by anonymous users."}`.

I am however logged out as an user.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually logged in, it's probably because a valid cookie from a previous session is still present in the request.

You can add/delete which cookies are to be sent along with the request, click on "Cookies" on the request pane (not be confused with the response cookie tab), see below :

[image]

Then just close the corresponding tab to delete the cookie :

[image]